# Overloading the = operator

Tags: c++, class, header, operator-overloading, implementation

I am overloading the `operator=` for a class that I have made. I did this for two classes, one of which it is working just fine and they both appear to be done correctly. One of the overloaded operators is not working. The program is not generating any errors it just is simple returning a blank version of the class. If anyone has any ideas as to what could be the problem it would be much appreciated.

.h file

```
Patient operator=(const Patient &right);
```

.cpp file

```cpp
 //Overloaded functions
Patient Patient::operator=(const Patient &right)
{
    Patient temp;

    temp.patientName = right.patientName;
    temp.age = right.age;
    temp.code = right.code;
    temp.problem = right.problem;
    temp.doctorName = right.doctorName;
    temp.roomNum = right.roomNum;
    temp.isWaiting = right.isWaiting;
    temp.isComplete = right.isComplete;

    return temp;
}
```

Part of the program it is being used for. I am aware of the random output messages, I was trying to locate where in the program I was having the issue. Narrowed it down to the `pat=p;` statement.

```cpp
void Room::setPat(Patient p)
{   
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    cout << p.getName() << pat.getName() << "end";

    pat = p;
    cout << p.getName() << pat.getName() << "end";
    cout << "End Test" << endl;
    patUsed = true;
 }
```

Comment: You know that the op= is supposed to change the "this" object, not some temporary?

Comment: Thank you for beginning my day with a laughter. `:)`

Comment: Apart form @PlasmaHH said, I think you are also doing the assignment otherwise. You need `p = pat;` which is `p.operator = (pat);`

Comment: Please don't provide your own copy operations if you just copy member-wise. Member-wise copying is what the compiler-generated operations would do anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the code you presented there is no need to write assignment operator. The compiler generated one will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the "tmp." Just delete it. And return a reference.

```
Patient& Patient::operator=(const Patient &right)
{
patientName = right.patientName;
age = right.age;
code = right.code;
problem = right.problem;
doctorName = right.doctorName;
roomNum = right.roomNum;
isWaiting = right.isWaiting;
isComplete = right.isComplete;
return *this;
}
```

Your original code do not modify the left operand of `=`, with is not the expect result.

If your `Patient` class **has no other member** that these, this `=`() definition is unnecessary and you can omit it. The compiler will generate it for you, with a “simple” assignment of each member, as pointed  *@sellibitze*. You define your onw `=`() only when you need something else, like a deep copy for example. I hope you are not copying here any pointer, and the class of each member have a “correct” `=`() self.

Comment: Am I squinting or is this just the same code, pasted from the question?!

Comment: +1. I'd add that such an operator is not really necessary at all since the compiler-generated one does the same thing (member-wise copy).

Comment: @PlasmaHH I wrote "You dont need the "tmp." Just delete it." And that is what I was doing :-) But it have to be suficient.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need not create any temps inside assignment operator.

2) Assignment operator should return a reference to itself.

Example [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr326.htm).

```
     //Overloaded functions
    Patient& Patient::operator=(const Patient &right)
    {
    patientName = right.patientName;
    age = right.age;
    code = right.code;
    problem = right.problem;
    doctorName = right.doctorName;
    roomNum = right.roomNum;
    isWaiting = right.isWaiting;
    isComplete = right.isComplete;
    return *this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not setting any of the values of the current object, instead you're just creating a new one and returning that.

```
Patient& Patient::operator=(const Patient &right)
{
    patientName = right.patientName;
    age = right.age;
    code = right.code;
    problem = right.problem;
    doctorName = right.doctorName;
    roomNum = right.roomNum;
    isWaiting = right.isWaiting;
    isComplete = right.isComplete;
    return *this;
}
```

Notice that the local variable has been removed, and you're instead assigning the class variables and a reference to the current class.